# Package Cordova Hook with a Plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I would like to package a bit of `before_build` logic as a hook with my plugin. Is it possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html

As a plugin developer you can define hook scripts using  elements in a plugin.xml like that:

```
<hook type="before_plugin_install" src="scripts/beforeInstall.js" />
<hook type="after_build" src="scripts/afterBuild.js" />

<platform name="wp8">
    <hook type="before_plugin_install" src="scripts/wp8BeforeInstall.js" />
    <hook type="before_build" src="scripts/wp8BeforeBuild.js" />
    ...
</platform>
```